# Subdivision on mirrored mesh not connected

Tags: subdivision-surface, mirror

I'm following Blender Guru's chair tutorial and have arrived at a state where upon extruding, the mirroring of the mesh "disconnects". I've been working left-to-right here. I was mirroring the two halves by hand. Then I deleted one half of the mesh, and just mirrored it. After, I tried extruding the back face of the mesh and have this weird behavior.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that there are no faces between the two part being mirrored?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @the-kalaakaar
There were indeed faces, as shown below. Removing them fixed the problem.
As a follow-up, how can I make sure to not create these faces when extruding?

[image]